# output variable with a hidden field

Tags: javascript, asp.net

i have a problem.I add value in hiddenField via js

```
function isEmail() {
        document.getElementById('hidden').innerHTML = "1111111";
    }

<input type="button" value="Button1" onclick="isEmail()">
<form id="Form1" runat = "server">
 <asp:HiddenField ID="hidden" runat="server" ></asp:HiddenField>
 <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button"     onclick="Button1_Click" ></asp:Button>
 <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
    </form>
```

I make a string variable which puts the value of the hidden field and deduce variable

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string hidden = this.hidden.Value;
    Label1.Text = "=" + hidden;

}
```

label is empty, why this code not work?
Thank

Comment: Don't use `innerHTML`, use `value`.

Comment: In other words, do this:  `document.getElementById('hidden').value = "1111111";`

Answer (score 0):

You are using an asp.net control, which means a unique client id will be generated. It won't be "hidden". You can try:

```
function isEmail() {
        document.getElementById('<%= hidden.ClientID %>').innerHTML = "1111111";
    }
```

Which will output the actual ClientID of your control into the script so it can be referenced.
Also, you can set the ClientIDMode of the HiddenField control to static which will cause it to generate the name as client id as "hidden".

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hidden" runat="server" ClientIDMode="static" ></asp:HiddenField>
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx